# Incrementally load data from a source data store to a destination data store in Azure blob

Tags: azure, blob

1. In azure blob created a file like output.json like same need to
   upload another file without deleting the old one..Because for that
   old file Junks already created any option is there to merge both
   files in azure blob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use Dataflow activity.

In Dataflow Activity, you have the option of alter row as shown in below image.
[image]
enter image description here

In Alter row you can use Upsert if condition.

[image]

Here mention condition as 1 == 1